# How to create parent accounts on Wordpress like 1 Google acc for Gmail, Youtube, Playstore..?

Tags: wordpress, parent, multisite, accounts

I'm creating a network of some websites that require a login on Wordpress. I was wondering if there was any way to have 1 account for all of the websites instead of creating a new one for each site?
Kind of like Google or Envato.

The websites are not the same in terms of functionality, so I'm thinking this could be a bit complicated.

I'm using 1 wordpress engine for multiple sites

Isn't there some kind of Wordpress plugin where I can update all user databases at once with the strings each sites have in common (e-mail, username & password)?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to make a wordpress account and login to each one with it as long as they are wordpress sites. Or you could use the wordpress "multisite feature" to make multiple sites off one dashboard.